# SQL BETWEEN Query returning incorrect results

Tags: .net, vb.net, ms-access

I am writing a vb.net application that is searching an Access 2010 database and have run into an issue I cannot seem to resolve.  The below segment of code is the issue.

```
 Using SQLcon 'public property containing OleDbConnection
    Dim ds As New DataSet
    Dim da As New OleDbDataAdapter
    Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand

    cmd.Connection = SQLcon
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text

    Dim heightMin As Double = OverallHeight - 0.25
    Dim heightMax As Double = OverallHeight + 0.125

    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM [CAGE - BARREL] WHERE [Type]=@p1 AND [Valve Size]=@p2 AND [Cage Height] BETWEEN @p3 AND @p4"
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p1", CageType) '[Type]
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p2", ValveSize) '[Valve Size]
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p3", heightMin) '[Cage Height]
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p4", heightMax) '[Cage Height]

    da = New OleDbDataAdapter(cmd)
    SQLcon.Open()
    da.Fill(ds, "[CAGE - BARREL]")
    SQLcon.Close()
End Using
```

When I run the SQL statement directly in Access with a particular set of values I get 3 results as expected.  When I run it through my program, I get 6 where 3 of the values are outside of my bounds for the BETWEEN statement. I've double checked the data types for the field in Access and the variables in vb.net.  I know I'm missing something.  Anyone out there have any ideas where I'm going wrong?

UPDATE:

The values in use are as follows.

```
@p1="INLET"
@p2="10.50" 'this is a text field
@p3=heightMin=6 'this is a number/double
@p4=heightMax=6.375 'this is a number/double
```

Values returned by the .net program include 5,5 and 3.688 which are outside of the bounds above and 6, 6, and 6.188 which are correct.

Comment: Can you [edit] your question to provide sample values that illustrate the problem? For example, "When I specify `OverallHeight` as ___ I get rows containing [Cage Height] values of ___ which are outside the range `heightMin` to `heightMax`.

Comment: Does it work if instead of using `.AddWithValue` you use, e.g., `cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter With {.ParameterName = "@p3", .OleDbType = OleDbType.Double, .Value = heightMin})`? (And similarly for the other parameters.)

Comment: [Cage - Barrel] is a table

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I cannot reproduce the problem (either).  That said, I would favor using some form of `>= AND <=` in place of `BETWEEN`.

Test data:

```
Id  CageType    ValveSize   Height
1     A            XS       0.25
2     A            S        0.51
3     A            S2       0.55
4     A            M        0.95
5     A            L        1.26
6     B            S        0.58
```

Code:

```
Dim sql1 = "SELECT * FROM Cage WHERE CageType=@p1 AND ValveSize=@p2 AND Height BETWEEN @p3 AND @p4"
Dim sql2 = "SELECT * FROM Cage WHERE ValveSize=@p2 AND Height BETWEEN @p3 AND @p4"

Dim t As String = "A"
Dim v As String = "S"
Dim minH As Double = 0.45
Dim maxH As Double = 0.65

Dim dt As New DataTable
Using dbcon As New OleDbConnection(ACEConnStr)
    Using cmd As New OleDbCommand(sql2, dbcon)
        dbcon.Open()

        ' only used with 'sql1':
        'cmd.Parameters.Add("@p1", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = t
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@p2", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = v
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@p3", OleDbType.Double).Value = minH
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@p4", OleDbType.Double).Value = maxH

        dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader)
        dgv1.DataSource = dt
    End Using
End Using
```

Result:

[image]

I assume there is something odd with your data or data types.  There are 2 SQL statements listed just for testing and reduce the amount of test data needed. `"SELECT * FROM Cage WHERE ValveSize=@p2 AND Height > @p3 AND Height <= @p4"` returns the same results.

Note that things like `OleDBConnection` and `OleDbCommand` allocate resources and ought to be disposed when you are done with them.  The `Using` statement does that for us.  I also used `Add` rather than `AddWithValue` so that the datatype can be specified, leaving VB/OleDB no room to guess at whats going on. Also, there is no need for a temp Adapter or `DataSet` - you can fill a `DataTable` directly with a `DataReader`.

Note also that `OleDb` does not use named parameters as such - they are simply positional placeholders.  With `OleDb` you *must* `Add` them in the exact order they appear in the SQL.  Yours does, but this explains why the code above can just comment out the `@p1` parameter and still work.

---

**Postscript**

As noted in the comments which may at some point get removed, the *real* issue was that the `OleDbCommand` was being resused.  Thus, it could have parameters or values left over from the last time.  This means the code posted is not the real code causing problems.

`DbCommand` objects are so query specific due to the parameters they may include  that it is another reason to create, use and dispose of them per use as a `Using` block does.

---

See Also:

- **[What do BETWEEN and the devil have in common?](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common)**
- **[Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/)**

(these are blogs - interesting opinions of Certain People of some repute - not the Word of Zeus carved in stone)

Answer (score 0):

I assume this is some funky OleDb-ness. In these situations you may as well just be explicit:

```
SELECT * 
FROM [CAGE - BARREL] 
WHERE [Type] = @p1 
    AND [Valve Size] = @p2 
    AND [Cage Height] >= @p3 
    AND [Cage Height] <= @p4
```

Comment: When using that method I get 0 records returned from my .net program.  It works perfectly in Access though. This is beyond frustrating.

Comment: @Mike very odd. are you sure it's not a data type issue? What are the data types of your parameters and what is the datatype of the `cage height` column?

Comment: Access is type Number, size double and the variables in my code are double.